# IE10 jquery weekly calendar no display all events on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-week-calendar

Issue:

When I load the calendar data all the other browsers have not problem displaying it, but IE10 does.

So far I made my ajax call to `cache: false`, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Now the odd thing is, in IE10 when you scroll up and down in the calendar the data show up. :(

Does anyone had the same issue before? if so, any suggestion?

Note: Sorry for my english.

============ ajax call for data =========

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/getData',
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        var classes = [];
            var len = data.content.length;

            for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
                var sDay = MAIN.calendar.getYearMonthDayNum().day(data.content[i].date),
                    eDay = MAIN.calendar.getYearMonthDayNum().day(data.content[i].date),
                    month = MAIN.calendar.getYearMonthDayNum().month(data.content[i].date),
                    year = MAIN.calendar.getYearMonthDayNum().year(data.content[i].date),

                    sHour = MAIN.calendar.getHourMinute24format().hour(data.content[i].start_time),
                    eHour = MAIN.calendar.getHourMinute24format().hour(data.content[i].end_time),
                    sMinutes = MAIN.calendar.getHourMinute24format().minutes(data.content[i].start_time),
                    eMinutes = MAIN.calendar.getHourMinute24format().minutes(data.content[i].end_time);

                classes.push({
                   "id":data.content[i].id,
                   "start": new Date(year, month, sDay, sHour, sMinutes),
                   "end": new Date(year, month, sDay, eHour, eMinutes),
                   "title":data.content[i].title,
                   "location": data.content[i].location != null ?  data.content[i].location.name : "",
                   "locationId": data.content[i].location != null ?  data.content[i].location.id : "",
                   "recurring": data.content[i].repeat_type,
                   "type": data.content[i].type,
                   "start_date" : data.content[i].start_date.substring(0, 10),
                   "end_date" : data.content[i].end_date.substring(0, 10),
                   "end_time" : data.content[i].end_time.substring(0, 5),
                   "start_time" : data.content[i].start_time.substring(0, 5),
                   readOnly : CANEDIT ? false : true
               });
            }

            MAIN.calendar.calData = classes;

            MAIN.calendar.generateCalendar();
    }
});
```

Comment: We would need to see your HTML and JS code to be able to help.

Comment: ok - i added the ajax call. what i notice is, I only have that problem when the calendar output a lot of data. ex: if only 20 events needed to display, everything is ok, if more that 50. that's when ie10 has display issues :(